# Arquillian: how to wait until text in element equals to some value

Tags: equals, wait, jboss-arquillian

I try to write Arquillian test. I would like to wait until ajax request is done (when the value on outputText is changed). I tried to achieve that using the following code:

```
Graphene.waitAjax().until().element(outputText).text().equals("something");
```

but it does not work (wait).

JSF code (on test.xhtml page):

```
<h:form id="myForm">
 <h:outputText value="#{controller.text}" id="textValue" />
  <h:commandButton value="change" id="changeButton">
   <f:ajax render="textValue" listener="#{myCounter.changeText()}" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Test method:

```
@Test
public void myTest(){
 browser.navigate().to(contextPath + "faces/test.xhtml");
 WebElement changeButtonElement = browser.findElement(By.id("myForm:changeButton"));
 WebElement valueElement = browser.findElement(By.id("myForm:textValue"));

 changeButtonElement.click();
 Graphene.waitAjax().until().element(valueElement).text().equals("something");
 assertEquals("something", valueElement.getText());
}
```

Output:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[something]> but was:<[init]>
```

Comment: Still I have a problems with `Graphene.waitAjax().until()`. On the other side `Graphene.guardAjax(someElement).click();` works fine. Unfortunately, it's not exactly what I wanted.